# I've just updated my Mac to Yosemite and now I can't open a .numbers file

Tags: macos, numbers

I have just updated my Mac to Yosemite and after that when I try to open .numbers file, I couldn't, and it gives me this message "edit 1.numbers can't be opened".

I do not know why and I really need this file.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem and don't have a permanent solution. However, if you email the file to yourself and open it from the email, it will open.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for the emailing solution! It lead me to a quicker one. I noticed that the email file had the extension .xls added to it. All you need to do is add .xls to files that are giving the "can't be opened" message and they seem to work again.